# Building lambda expression that has "as" keyword in it

Tags: c#, lambda, build, expression

I have a model where there is a class `Division` and a class `SubDivision` that inherits from `Division`, now I would like to build an expression of type `Expressions<Func<Division, object>>>` that has the following body `x => (x as SubDivision).SubDivisionProperty`. Is this possible?

Comment: [`TypeAs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.typeas(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I didn't have the chance to try it yet, but the documentation says that it is what I am looking for, thanks a lot. feel free to post it as an answer and I will mark it as correct.